# write strings to the bottom line of an textfile

Tags: java

i want to write strings to a textfile, everytime to the bottom of the file. And then if im searching for a certain string in the textfile and finds it, i want to replace that line with another.

I'm thinking this: Count rows in textfile and add +1 and then write the string i want to write to that index. But is it even possible to write to a certain linenumber in a textfile?

And how about to update a certain row to another string ?

thanks!

Comment: What have u tried already?, show us your code pls

Answer (score 4):

You do not want to do that: it is a recipe for disaster. If, during the original file modification, you fail to write to it, the original file will be corrupted.

Use a double write protocol, write the modified file to another file, and *only if the write suceeds*, rename that file to the original.

Provided your file is not too big, for some definition of "big", I'd recommend creating a `List<String>` for the destination file: read the original file line by line, add to that list; once the list processing is complete (your question is unclear what should really happen), write each `String` to the other file, flush and close, and if that succeeds, rename to the original.

Comment: What is the relationship with the original question? Are you sure you didn't mean that comment to go somewhere else? :p

Comment: Sorry, clicked enter before i was done. I'm creating a online tick-tack-toe game, and i've got a login website, so you got to have an account. If you'are a new user we need to write information on the bottom of the textfile (with accounts info: Username, password, total wins and total losses). If you're not a new user and ie. plays a game, we'll need to update the winning player's line and the other players line too. As it is now i read all lines into an arraylist, and modify the elements and then write whole arraylist to file. If my server disconnects then it will be problem as it is now. :P

Comment: The [Files.readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) and [Files.write(Path, Iterable, Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) methods should make this approach pretty easy.

Comment: Since it is an online game, why don't you keep the list of subscription in memory and only serialize it on shutdown/deserialize it on startup?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to append strings, the FileOutputStream [does have an alternate constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) which you can set to true so you can open for appending.
2. If you'd like, say, to replace strings into a *file without copying it*, your best bet would be to rely in [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) instead. However, if the line length is varying, this is unreliable. For fixed-length records, this should work as such:

   - Move to the offset
   - Write

You can also 'truncate' (via setLength), so if there's a trailing block you need to get rid, you could discard as such.

A Third Solution would be to rely in mmap. This requires on a [Memory-Mapped Bytebuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) for the whole file. I'm not considering the whole feasibility of the solution (it works in plain C), but that actually 'looks' the more correct, if you consider both the Java Platform + the Operating System

Comment: If you have to modify the input file, you had better go through a "double write" protocol instead: it is safer on the whole.

Comment: Can you give me some pointers on what could a "double write protocol" be? The concept looks familiar, but I'd like to see if we're on the same page.

Comment: I'm not discussing safety, but algorithms and filesystem semantics. Reliability concerns are best left to the implementor :)

Comment: Well, a journaling filesystem is an example: you first write to a journal, and write to the actual storage if and only if the journal write succeeds. It is not really a "protocol" per se, more of a general algorithm which says "write modifications elsewhere, reflect to original only on success".

Comment: But thats not a log. The log writes the changed pages - if they're using COW semantics, then its the copy you've mentioned (this is likely not to happen). OTOH, what I've outlined is called ISAM. :)